# How to multiply NSstring by the number?

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, multiplication

I can't multiply `currentValue` variable value.

Code:

```
 @IBAction func PlusMinus()
{
    let v = 0
    command = nil
    let currentValue = v
    let v = v*(-1)
    displayLabel!.text = m
    }
```

what is wrong ?
You can see screenshot :
http://cl.ly/image/3c2e0V0m021H

Comment: Try to avoid linking to screenshots hosted in other sites. Instead, use the "attach image" button you have while typing your question

Comment: ...or simply report the error text and location. No need for images here.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining a constant with the same name 'v'. Also, you're using several instance vars in your code. Copy all relevant code in your question.

```swift
@IBAction func PlusMinus()
{
    let v = 0
    command = nil
    let currentValue = v
    let v = v*(-1)  // you've already defined a constant named 'v'
    displayLabel!.text = m
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` declares a constant. It's like writing `2 = 2 * (-1)`, makes no sense. Use `var` for variable values.